# Regex replace in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a sentence like this one:

> `[FindThis|foo|bar] with some text between [FindThis|foo|bar]. [FindThis|foo|bar] and some more text.`

I want to regex replace this sentence so that i get:

> `FindThis with some text between FindThis. FindThis and some more text.`

How can I achieve this? Really been trying all morning, the only thing I've came up with is:

```
Regex.Replace(myString, @"\[(\w).*\]", "$1");
```

Which only gives me:

> `F and some more text.`

Comment: @Oded: This won't work, since the `.*` is greedy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace

```
\[([^|]+)[^\]]+]
```

by `$1`.

A little explanation:

```
\[      match the opening bracket
[^|]+   match the first part up to the |
        (a sequence of at least one non-pipe character)
[^\]]+  match the rest in the brackets
        (a sequence of at least one non-closing-bracket character)
]       match the closing bracket
```

Since we stored the first part in the brackets in a capturing group we replace the whole match with the contents of that group.

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> $text = '[FindThis|foo|bar] with some text between [FindThis|foo|bar]. [FindThis|foo|bar] and some more text.'
PS> $text -replace '\[([^|]+)[^\]]+]','$1'
FindThis with some text between FindThis. FindThis and some more text.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have other replacements with no "alternatives", e.g. `[FindThat] with text in between [Find|the|other]`, you need a slight change to the regex:

```
\[([^|\]]+)[^\]]*]
```

The explanation:

> ```
> \[      match the opening bracket  
> [^|\]]+ match the first part up to the | or ]  
>         (a sequence of at least one non-pipe or closing-bracket character)  
> [^\]]*  match the rest in the brackets  
>         (a sequence of any non-closing-bracket characters including none)  
> ]       match the closing bracket
> ```

<sub>Much of this answer copied from Joey's.</sub>